# How to schedule a service to run in android

Tags: android, android-service

I have a Service in my app that make some API request and use the data supplied in the response, is there a way to schedule the service to run in every hour 
Thank you

Comment: any more detail or example would be helpful , thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that's how i did it at the end :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProximityAlertService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Log.d("Main",String.valueOf( cal.getTimeInMillis()));
//make the alarm goes off every 10 sec (not exact help to save battery life)
alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 10000, pintent);
```

Comment: that's interesting. any idea how much of a drain on the battery would this really be? Would it reduce the standby time by a couple of minutes or upto an hour?

Comment: As far as i can remember the impact wasn't major in that scenario, but i guess it depends what your service is actually doing .

Answer (score 1):

an eg:

```
    AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, LocationPoller.class);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    LocationPollerParameter parameter = new LocationPollerParameter(bundle);
    parameter.setIntentToBroadcastOnCompletion(new Intent(context, MyStartServiceReceiver.class));
    // try GPS and fall back to NETWORK_PROVIDER
    parameter.setProviders(new String[] {LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER});
    parameter.setTimeout(60000);
    i.putExtras(bundle);


    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 54321, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Start 30 seconds after boot completed
    service.cancel(pending);
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
    //
    // Fetch every 30 seconds
    // InexactRepeating allows Android to optimize the energy consumption
    service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);
```